# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated' has no attribute 'templates'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

federated_algorithm = tff.templates.IterativeProcess(
initialize_fn = initialize_fn, next_fn = next_fn)

TF=2.1.0
Tff=0.13.0

they are showing attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

The `tff.templates` package was not available until TFF versions `0.14.0` and later. Prior to this, the `IterativeProcess` symbol existed in the `tff.utils` package.

See the [`0.14.0` release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.14.0) for details about this change.